# how can I update this observable collection more efficiently?

Tags: c#

I am trying to update an object that contains an observable collection that contains another observable collection.  The following code works, but it is ugly.  How can I improve this?

ProfileBO contains the Observable Collection ZoneBOList.  ZoneBOList contains the Observable Collection ZoneMonitorBOList.  ZoneMonitorBOList IS the object collection for the object I am trying to add.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
   ZoneMonitorBO zoneMonitorBO = new ZoneMonitorBO();
   zoneMonitorBO.ZoneId = (int)reader["zone_id"];
   zoneMonitorBO.MonitorId = (int)reader["monitor_id"];

   ZoneBO zoneBO = new ZoneBO();
   //Pluck off the object from the observable collection that we need to update
   zoneBO = profileBO.ZoneBOList.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ZoneID == zoneMonitorBO.ZoneId);
   //Add the business object to the observable collection of the observable collection 
   zoneBO.ZoneMonitorBOList.Add(zoneMonitorBO);
   //remove the old object                        
   profileBO.ZoneBOList.Remove(profileBO.ZoneBOList.Where(c => c.ZoneID == zoneMonitorBO.ZoneId).Single());
   //add the updated object to the 'parent' observable collection
   profileBO.ZoneBOList.Add(zoneBO);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me your entire code looks inconsistent:

- Why you creating and reassign ZoneBO?
- Why you looking for it second time? You do understand that you add the same object you modified then deleted by reference?
- Why you need to remove it and add again into collection?
- What if FirstOrDefault returns null and you get an exception?

Until you answer for this questions, all this can be simplified to just this:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
   var zoneMonitorBO = new ZoneMonitorBO();
   zoneMonitorBO.ZoneId = (int)reader["zone_id"];
   zoneMonitorBO.MonitorId = (int)reader["monitor_id"];

   var zoneBO = profileBO.ZoneBOList.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ZoneId == zoneMonitorBO.ZoneId);
   if(zoneBO != null)
   {
       zoneBO.ZoneMonitorBOList.Add(zoneMonitorBO);
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok I got it.  you just pluck it off of the collection and update it, and by reference it updates the ProfileBO object that contains it!  Fantastic!!  Works perfectly.  Thanks you!!!!